# How to remove model validation from spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am struggling with this issue for more than 6 hours.

I want to remove the validation from `Spree::Order`

```
module Spree
  class Order < Spree::Base
    MONEY_THRESHOLD  = 100_000_000
    MONEY_VALIDATION = {
      presence:     true,
      numericality: {
        greater_than: -MONEY_THRESHOLD,
        less_than:     MONEY_THRESHOLD,
        allow_blank:   true
      },
      format:       { with: /\A-?\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?\z/, allow_blank: true }
    }.freeze

    NEGATIVE_MONEY_VALIDATION = MONEY_VALIDATION.deep_dup.tap do |validation|
      validation.fetch(:numericality)[:less_than_or_equal_to] = 0
    end.freeze

    validates :promo_total,          NEGATIVE_MONEY_VALIDATION

    # ...
  end
end
```

This is my decorator

```
Spree::Order.class_eval do
  # This is not working
  _validators.delete(:promo_total)

  # Nope
  _validators.reject!{ |key, _| key == :promo_total }

  # Nope
  def validate
    errors = self.errors.map {|attr, message| [attr, message]}
    self.errors.clear
    errors.each do |attr, message|
      self.errors.add(attr, message) unless attr == "promo_total"
    end
  end
  # ...
end
```

When I am checking for the validation I am getting the error on `:promo_total`

```
self.valid?
#=> false

self.errors.messages
#=> {:promo_total=>["must be less than or equal to 0"]}
```

Comment: Hi, any luck with this one?

Comment: No, we used different solution to achieve what we needed

Comment: Hi, I just found out that we need to remove the attribute from both `_validators` and `_validate_callbacks`, below is a snippet.

`Spree::Product._validators.delete(:name)`

`Spree::Product._validate_callbacks.each do |callback|
  if callback.raw_filter.respond_to? :attributes
    callback.raw_filter.attributes.delete :name
  end
end`

Let me know if this works for you as well.

Comment: That seems great.. Why don't you post it as answer.. maybe it will help someone with the same problem

Answer (score 1):

You should try with this gem https://github.com/workarea-commerce/active_model-unvalidate

Even in latest version should work

Comment: Kindly add context to any links so your Answer is self contained, meaning the answer needs to be here in the Answer itself. See ["Provide context for links"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). It would be preferable if you could answer the Question in your own words here and link only as a reference. What is it? How is it used?